# Как в боте telegram сделать перевод строки?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

Нужен перенос сроки в сообщении бота телеграм! **Как сделать то?**

у меня сообщение отправляется так:

```
sendMessage($id_contact, 'Укажите Ф.И.О. клиента! \r\%2F Если имени нет поставьте "нет", в любой момент можете завершить добавление командой /done или готово

function sendMessage($idchat, $message) {
  file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $idchat . '&text=' . urlencode($message).'');
}
```

пробовал и `<br>` и `\r\n` и `\r\%2F` ничего не помогает...

Вот что бот выдает:

```
Укажите Ф.И.О. клиента! \n Если имени нет поставьте "нет", в любой момент можете завершить добавление командой /done или готово
```

Comment: [Подсказка](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: @D-side, подсказка может и хорошая, но я честно сказать не пойму что я не так делаю

Comment: @D-side вот никогда не понимал людей которые дают ссылки на Английскую версию вместо Русской.

Comment: @Naumov гугл выдал английскую :) Так вышло. Дайте человеку русскую, раз так.

Comment: @D-side http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: Ещё подсказка: добавьте в вопрос, что происходит, если поставить в строку `\r\n`.

Comment: @D-side сообщение отправляется, вот так бот выдает "Укажите Ф.И.О. клиента! \n Если имени нет поставьте "нет", в любой момент можете завершить добавление командой /done или готово"

Comment: Прямо в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: бот причём вообще в этом вопросе? про телеграм апи вообще молчу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина была в том, что у меня было заключено в '' скобки сообщение, поставив обычные "" и внутри них срабатывает \r\n

Comment: А что такое обычные ""? А это '' разве не обычные? :)

Comment: @Visman вот реально поменял кавычки в формировании сообщений и  заработало

Comment: Он не являются обычными и необычными, они являются двойными и одинарными.

Comment: Ур-ра-а, вы догадались! :)

Answer (score 1):

Люди так делают: `первая строка`**%0A**`вторая строка`

Comment: Это не ответ - это комментарий.

Answer (score 0):

самый правильный ответ!'.chr(10).'

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: все перепробовал, но самый правильный ответ!'.chr(10).'

Answer (score 0):

мне на C# помогла следующая реализация

```
    .Replace("<br>", "\n");
```

причем когда пишу /n - хоть в каких кавычках, не делает переход. а при замене - все ок!